# DatagramSocket with a public ip address

Tags: java, sockets

hello everyone i'm making an application that uses DatagramSocket to transmit data between Pc and android Phone it works when i use a local ip Address but when i use ddns from no-ip or my public ip address it didn't i work i get this error message

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port,InetAddress.getByName("XXXXX.ddns.net"));
```

i got this error message : 
java.net.BindException: `Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind`

plz help me how can i establish a connection between two machines using no-ip ddns instead of my local ip address

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind an addresses that are configured on network interfaces on the device you use. I don't know your home network setup but most likely your public IP address is configured on the router/modem you use to connect to the internet so this simply will not work.

Your router may have port forwarding feature where it sends packets sent to a specific port to a specific IP address in your home network. You would have to configure a static IP address on the device and set up port forwarding to that address.